# Chatter 'Following' list on profile page won't consistently update. Ideas?

Tags: lightning-experience, chatter, user-profile, follow

I'm prepping to do some Chatter training and I see that to find out who we're Following, we go to our personal profile page. I do see this, and to test I've hit 'Follow' on a variety of records. The 'Following' list is not updating consistently. It includes people that I 'Follow' from a Chatter recommended list, but not when I 'Follow' directly on a Contact record (though 'Follow' there does change to 'Following' with a checkmark). What am I missing?

**Bonus question/clarification:** The 'Following' list in LEX displays only people, no other records. Expected behavior? There is no evidence of how to see Accounts, Opportunities, or any other record I'm following (was hoping to add more Related Lists to Page Layouts, but no clues there). One line in the [Follow People and Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_following.htm&type=5) article says *In Salesforce Classic, you can see the people and records that you follow and the people who are following you.* So do I take that to mean in LEX you cannot?

Comment: Hmm, did you click 'show all' in the followers ui?   If thats not helpful you might want to explore the following REST endpoint in your Developer Console to help you troubleshoot the concern: `/services/data/v50.0/chatter/users/someUserId/following?page=1` and analyze the results to answer the following: Do your REST queries for what someone follows agree or disagree with what you see in the LEX / Classic UI?

Comment: I clicked 'View All' yes. I'm afraid I'd need a dev to explain the rest of what you're saying. But overnight I can confirm that nothing has changed. I have Contacts that on their record clearly indicate I am Following, but they do not appear in the Following list on my profile.

Comment: It seems like a limitation of LEX. Upvote it here and read the comments on the same page because some users are explaining potential workarounds: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003WHSQA2